What should I do after seeing the results from dumpbin.exe command?
I am trying to build and install the gtk4 plugin from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs for a Haskell project. I have followed all the instructions written in Rust using Visual Studio Code as an IDE, and it looked as if it succeded but when I ran gst-inspect-1.0 gstgtk4 I got the following warning message
(gst-plugin-scanner.exe:9876): GStreamer-WARNING **: 16:16:29.798: Failed to load plugin 'D:\visual-studio-projects\gstreamer-gst-plugins-rs\-gst-plugins-rs\target\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\debug\gstgtk4.dll': Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata
No such element or plugin 'gstgtk4' saying that gstreamer failed to load the plugin.

I then ran gst-inspect-1.0 -b to see if the plugin got somehow blacklisted and it did, I got the following:
PS C:\Users\bu> gst-inspect-1.0 -b
Blacklisted files:
  gstamrnb.dll
  gstamrwbdec.dll
  gstgtk4.dll

Total count: 3 blacklisted files

Following the instructions from Matilda Gl's answer Why compiled and installed gstreamer plugin from boilerplate code is not found by gst-inspect I first tried deleting directory ~/.cache/ (the question was asked from a Linux user, for Windows I assume it's C:\Users\user.cache , correct me if I'm wrong) and then ran gst-inspect-1.0 again but nothing happened. She said that Gstreamer would print out the reason why it blacklisted the plugin but I got no message.
The last step was to run dumpbin -dependents D:\visual-studio-projects\gstreamer-gst-plugins-rs\gst-plugin-rs\target\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\debug\gstgtk4.dll to see if I had any missing dependencies for the gstgtk4 plugin as Sourab Maity suggested in Failed to load plugin GStreamer and I did. This is the command output:
Dump of file D:\visual-studio-projects\gstreamer-gst-plugins-rs\gst-plugin-rs\target\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\debug\gstgtk4.dll

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    bcryptprimitives.dll
    api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
    gstgl-1.0-0.dll
    gstvideo-1.0-0.dll
    gstbase-1.0-0.dll
    gstreamer-1.0-0.dll
    gobject-2.0-0.dll
    glib-2.0-0.dll
    gtk-4-1.dll
    graphene-1.0-0.dll
    gio-2.0-0.dll
    kernel32.dll
    ntdll.dll
    VCRUNTIME140.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll

  Summary

        1000 .data
        7000 .pdata
       38000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
       72000 .text

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools>

The following dependencies are missing from D:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\msvc_x86_64\\bin : bcryptprimitives.dll, api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll, gtk-4-1.dll, kernel32.dll, ntdll.dll, VCRUNTIME140.dll, api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll, api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll, api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll, api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll.
So now I don't really know how to solve this problem. Do I just download all of these dependencies separately and copy them over the bin directory? Would that be enough?
Or should I try reinstalling gstreamer and see if they get installed this time?
I also ran Dependency Walker program to inspect these missing dependencies a little bit better and found out that a lot of them come from c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\windows performance toolkit\ . I tried updating the SDKs from Windows but nothing happened still.
